# How to model spiral

Tags: modeling

Is this possible to model this spiral kinda thing? How can I do this? 
Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, maybe there is a simpler way?

- Create your shape profile, keep the origin where the pivot point needs to be.
- Add a *Screw* modifier to your object, with a 360° Angle, play with the *Screw* factor, add some *Steps* to make the mesh smoother, choose the amount of *Iterations* you need.
- Apply your modifier in Object mode
- Go in Edit mode and *W* > *Remove Doubles* so that the mesh vertices join themselves and leave no gaps between the iterations, play with *Merge Distance* factor on the bottom of the T menu.
- Cut the top of the mesh
- Merge some vertices on the top edge loop to simplify it.
- Flatten it in the Z axis with *S+Z+0*
- With the top edge loop still selected, enable the *LoopTools* addon, if it is not already, and make a *W* > *LoopTools* > *Circle*.
- Extrude this top edge loop.
- Do the same thing for the bottom (clean the mesh, make a circle, extrude...)
- Give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to smooth it, and click *Shading* > *Smooth* in the T menu.

[image]